# Cant get npm to download jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm

I am trying to learn npm. I am on a windows machine running git bash command line. When I run npm install jquery, I get the following error and no jQuery folder is downloaded into my project folder.

I can't seem to find a working answer, and when I google each error, each error doesnt seem to stop the download, it is just a warning.

Here is the versions I am running:

node: v8.11.2

npm: v6.1.0

Error:

$ npm install jquery
npm WARN chris@1.0.0 No description

npm WARN chris@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm WARN The package eslint-config-google is included as both a dev and production dependency.

jquery@3.3.1
added 1 package from 1 contributor and audited 237 packages in 2.225s
found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: It seems just to be a warning. The package should be installed.

Comment: When you say your project folder I wonder what you mean - it should be in your project folder in your `node_modules` folder.

Comment: npm install --save jquery

Comment: I have created a folder on my desktop for the udemy course, connected it to github. On the course, all he has done is had us install node, changed directories to the website folder with his default files and run npm install jquery

Comment: npm install --save jquery didnt work either

Answer (score 0):

Are you positive you're looking in the right place for jquery? It should be in the node_modules subdirectory of the directory you were in when you ran `npm install jquery`.

You are getting the warnings because you're not in an npm initialized directory. Use `npm init` to initialize the directory and the warnings will go away.

When you `npm install jquery`, also do a `dir` from the command line, you should see a node_modules folder, jquery will be inside it.

Comment: I ran the npm init command and went through the prompts, and it created a few files/folders in my project folder. The node_modules folder, the package and the package_lock file. Then reran npm install jquery, then ran the dir command and no jquery folder

Comment: The jquery folder should be inside the node_modules folder.

Comment: I opened git bash in admin and this solution then worked, thank you!